# Excluding categories in Wordpress with "list_terms_exclusions" not showing results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the filter `list_terms_exclusions` to exclude categories in the Wordpress admin panel for users with a certain role. The following code is what I have put together:

```
add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'nsf_exclude_cats', 20 );
function nsf_exclude_cats( $exclusions ) {
    global $pagenow;
    global $nsf_exclude; // array from another function, with all the cat_ID's to be excluded

    if (current_user_can( 'krets_editor' ) && is_admin() ) {
        $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id NOT IN (';
        foreach($nsf_exclude as $exclude) {
            $exclusions .= $exclude.',';
        }
        $exclusions = substr($exclusions, 0, -1); // Removing the last comma
        $exclusions .= ')';
    }
return $exclusions;
}
```

This is "almost working". When I go to "Categories" in Wordpress admin, I see that the total counted categories is correct (there is over 200 categories, but 8 should be returned for this user). But the table is empty (!), no categories are shown!

[image]

**But if I press the "Name" column header for example, to sort the results so the URL is changed with the orderby parameter, it is working as intended and the table is filled. What am I missing here that is the reason for the results not showing in the default view?**

[image]

Comment: Seems like this might be a hierarchically problem. The primary categories (top level) are shown, but any child categories is not displayed as described above.

Comment: Have you checked the `$args` parameter that is involved in the query (and passed as 2nd argument to your used filter hook) and its contents? According to https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php#L401 there are some parameters involved that could be linked to your issue and the hierarchical stuff. There is a filter `get_terms_args`  that let's you alter the `$args` that are taken into the query which is called a few lines above `list_terms_exclusions`. Maybe both hooks used in conjunction brings you closer to your desired goal.

Comment: I tried to "reproduce" your problem. Your code **IS WORKING ABSOLUTELY FINE ON MY END**! Everything is working as expected. BUT, why it's not working on your end? I'm suspicious of your custom capability you assigned to your role! So in order to debug it, FIRST try to replace `current_user_can( 'krets_editor' )` with `current_user_can('administrator')` and make sure your admin role could see your categories as expected. If there is no problem viewing your categories as an admin, then it could be your custom capability and/or corrupted/obsolete wordpress core file(s).

Comment: @mynd I have not checked that parameter so far. I will dig into it and test if that extra hook and som modified code can do the trick. I'll let you know what I find out, thanks!

Comment: @Ruvee Very interesting theory, and I thought this might be it, until I tried it. Sadly the same result for admin user. What I was thinking about now, is that this site has copied content from an older Wordpress-installation (both posts and categories). Might be that some relations within the category structure got screwed over in the import, but it's seems odd to me that I can see the categories correctly when I sort the table. It also display the correct categories when using an ACF relationship drop down field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying only child categories in wp-admin for chosen user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272416/displaying-only-child-categories-in-wp-admin-for-chosen-user-roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am checking your code we found a very small  issue with **$nsf_exclude**

$nsf_exclude = empty (no category id exist), that's why your function restricts all categories. but if you click on sorting then cat id set in your global variable that's why it's visible by click on sorting.

====== Debugging ======

1. Proper set cat id $nsf_exclude
2. print $nsf_exclude. eg print_r($nsf_exclude);
3. If page onload/refresh return/print cat ids then it will work
4. Other way set cat id manuall and verify

   eg. global $nsf_exclude;

   $nsf_exclude = array(115,136);

=========== Working Function ===================

```
add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'nsf_exclude_cats', 20 );
function nsf_exclude_cats( $exclusions ) {
    global $pagenow;
    global $nsf_exclude; // array from another function, with all the cat_ID's to be excluded
    $nsf_exclude = array(115,136); 
    if (current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && is_admin() ) {
        if(!empty($nsf_exclude)){
            $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id NOT IN (';
            foreach($nsf_exclude as $exclude) {
                $exclusions .= $exclude.',';
            }
            $exclusions = substr($exclusions, 0, -1); // Removing the last comma
            $exclusions .= ')';
        }
    }
    return $exclusions;
}
```

---

**Note:**

After test remove or comment $nsf_exclude = array(115,136);

Where 115,136 is the product category ids (you can replace with own cat ids)

Comment: I hear you, did a test with printing the global variable $nsf_exclude. Seems that it's not empty though: [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/OWfF5UI)

Comment: Thanks for sharing screenshots, Now we got exactly the issue that you are facing. suppose i have 5 category id like: 114,115,116,136,137 and i have set 2 category id(115,136) in global variable like: $nsf_exclude = array(115,136); When i execute this, we will get 3 category (114,116,137) in category grid, means $nsf_exclude assign category id will will visible on category grid.

Comment: As I am checking your screenshot I think you assign all category id in global variable $nsf_exclude. that's why the category grid is empty on page load/refresh. If you have 1000 categories and you want to visible 200 categories out of 1000, so should unset/remove 200 category id out of 1000 from $nsf_exclude.

Comment: In sort, $nsf_exclude assign category id will not be visible on the category grid. I hope you understand what I am saying.
you should set/assign only hidden category id on $nsf_exclude, not all category id.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I understood that you meant, but actually there was 9 category_ids that was not in the array, and should be shown. However, your answer got me thinking, and the problem was way stupider than expected. The 9 categories that did not show in the table, had parent categories which id's was in the array. In other words, the parents of the categories I wanted to show got excluded, therefore also the childs. Removing the parents from $nsf_exclude and it works (of course!!)